# Python and GridSearchCV how to eliminate input contains NaN error when using cross validation and decision tree classifier?

Tags: python, decision-trees, cross-validation, grid-search

I am trying to do cross validation on Decision tree classifier for kaggle's titanic dataset. The first step after cleaning data is to split into train and test sets:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
```

Then transform numbers into scaled values:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
x_train = sc.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = sc.transform(x_test)
```

In addition:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier()
```

For the grid search, I used GridSearchCV:

```
#Make a grid search
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
tree_param = [{'criterion': ['entropy', 'gini'], 'max_depth': [2,3, 4]}]
```

And at the end to fit the GridSearchCV classifier into data:

```
clf = GridSearchCV(classifier, tree_param, cv=4)
clf.fit(X=x_train, y=y_train)
```

The error I am getting is as follows:

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for
>   dtype('float32').

I checked my `x_train` and `y_train` sets, and they both contains numeric values within a specific range:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that the datasets are as Data Frames.

Once I read them using:

```
X = X.iloc[:, [0,8]].values
```

It was transformed into `int32` list and the error gone.

Comment: your X here isnt in the initial post. what did you transform?

Answer (score 1):

You should impute missing values, try with:

```py
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
imp.fit(x_train)
x_train = imp.transform(x_train)
x_test = imp.transform(x_test)
```

Notice that I am fiting just in the train data, so you are not leaking information to the test.

Comment: Well it could be the answer, but when I transformed the dataframe into array of int32 before scaling. It worked.